# Add Permission For Lock Screen Notification Android Programmatically

Tags: java, android, push-notification

In My Android App, I Can't Able to Enable Lockscreen notification. As you can see in the Screenshot all the options are disabled. How to Enable this option Programmatically? Currently, I'm Testing This App into my  MI Xiaomi Phone and having this issue. How can solve this ?  Please Check the Screenshot Bellow and give me a suggestion for this problem. thanks

[image]

I Already Tired This Code But Notification Not Showing in the Lock Screen As Mainly I cant able to enable this permission.

Here is my Code :

```
    package maxpro.com.ramadantime.BoradCastReceiver;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.AudioAttributes;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import maxpro.com.ramadantime.MainActivity;
import maxpro.com.ramadantime.R;
import maxpro.com.ramadantime.Splash.SplashActivity;

import static android.content.Context.POWER_SERVICE;

public class MyBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Notification notification;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    @Override
        public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
        {

            // Logic to turn on the screen
            PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);

            if (!powerManager.isInteractive()){ // if screen is not already on, turn it on (get wake_lock for 10 seconds)
                @SuppressLint("InvalidWakeLockTag") PowerManager.WakeLock wl = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,"MH24_SCREENLOCK");
                wl.acquire(10000);
                @SuppressLint("InvalidWakeLockTag") PowerManager.WakeLock wl_cpu = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"MH24_SCREENLOCK");
                wl_cpu.acquire(10000);
            }

            try {
                Uri myUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.m);
               mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context,myUri);
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();
            // Put here YOUR code.
            Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example
            showNotification("notification","alarm",context);

        }

        public void setAlarm (Context context)
        {
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MyBroadCastReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
        }

        public void cancelAlarm (Context context)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadCastReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(sender);
        }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void showNotification(String title, String message, Context context) {
        AudioAttributes att = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                .build();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
        String channel_id = "notification";
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+context.getPackageName()+"/" + R.raw.m);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channel_id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.background)
                .setSound(uri)
                .setContentTitle("Weekly Alarm")
                .setContentText("beeeep")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        //wake up device and show even when on lock screen
        final long[] DEFAULT_VIBRATE_PATTERN = {0, 250, 250, 250};
        builder.setVibrate(DEFAULT_VIBRATE_PATTERN);
        builder.setLights(Color.WHITE, 2000, 3000);
        builder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);

// This is the answer to OP's question, set the visibility of notification to public.
        builder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

    }
    }
```

> With this Code I can go to Notification Setting But I want to Enable it Programmitically, not showing it to user

```
public static void goToNotificationSettings(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        intent.setData(Uri.fromParts(SCHEME, context.getPackageName(), null));
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
        intent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
        intent.putExtra("app_package", context.getPackageName());
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        intent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
        intent.putExtra("app_package", context.getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra("app_uid", context.getApplicationInfo().uid);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
    } else {
        return;
    }
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: did you add the required permissions? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />

Comment: yes I did this but still it doesn't work

Comment: You can't do that programmatically. It defeats the purpose of giving the user control over notifications. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications

Comment: Did u solve the issue @TasnuvaTavasumoshin ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently MIUI doesn't allow to do that programmatically. Even if you create a notification channel with a lock screen visibility and sound turned on.

Comment: Check apps like yandex go and other. There is enabled by default